# C++ with 2 compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I have a project which I would like to code on both an Ubuntu and a Windows machine. On Ubuntu I'm using gcc, and on windows I would like to use MSVC.

Is it a good idea to compile the same code with 2 different compilers like this? Or would I run into issues down the road?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, compiling with two independent compilers is healthy. Make sure that you clear the warning messages that they might emit (not by disabling them, preferably by understanding and fixing them). From my experience, code that compiles fine on two sides also runs both sides.

Comment: You're likely to run into issues down the road but that shouldn't stop you. You may need to use some platform-dependent code, which is usually handled by a "platform.h" file of sorts. This file makes the appropriate defines based on the compiler and platform, so you don't clutter your codebase with platform-specific defines.

Comment: @TomášZato: What makes you think that Programmers is for questions with no problem to solve?

Comment: @TomášZato Programmers.SE also expects questions to be about a specific problem of some kind (or at least a tractably small class of problems). We have the same "too broad" close reason as SO does. The actual distinction is that we focus on software design questions rather than debugging/implementation questions.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet [The list of top voted questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), none of those on first page is closed. Most of those ask what is good practice or what is better, just as this question does, none asks for solution for a specific problem in a specific situation.

Comment: @TomášZato: You'll find hundreds of similar highly-voted questions on SO. That doesn't mean they define the rules.

Comment: If one of the compilers is MSVC, then it is absolutely a good idea, if for no other reason, to perform sanity checks on it.

Comment: Can I just move this question to the right place? Or would I have to re-ask it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is an excellent idea. In the past, I've found a bunch of bugs in my code that I could only see after switching compilers.

Comment: Oh I never thought that they'd catch different errors, that's a great point! Was there ever a time where you couldn't get code to compile on one compiler, just because of differences in how they work? 
I read somewhere that msvc is a little different to gcc, which adheres to the c++ standards more closely.

Comment: Yes. Even the same compiler, but different versions. Each successive version of gcc tends to be less tolerant of small violations of C++ rules, that the earlier version of gcc tended to ignore.

Comment: You can always rewrite the code so that it compiles on both platforms (the changes required are usually obvious).  The slightly scary case is they both compile but only one works; TEST ON BOTH PLATFORMS!!  (That usually happens when you have accidentally introduced undefined behaviour, but one platform does what you were expecting it to do.)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to compile for different platforms, you *have* to compile with different compilers (even if they are different versions of the same compiler).

If you compile with both GCC and MSVC, you will find you can't use a lot of the extensions that each compiler provides.  You will also find annoyances like MSVC puts an underscore on the front of functions like `_open`.  Basically, this comes down to "welcome to the wonderful world of portable coding".

On the other hand, once you start writing code for two compilers, it becomes much easier to add a third - and I would recommend adding Clang to the mix as a cheap and cheerful static analysis tool.

Comment: Don't give the gcc folks any bright ideas. Like adding a win32 target to the Linux version.

Comment: What?  You mean like Mingw?

Comment: Isn't mingw a native Windows port? I was referring to adding a win32 cross-compilation target to the Linux version. Which would make it possible to technically use the same compiler to build both ELF and win32 binaries.

Comment: It's basically gcc with a win32 code generator that is compiled for win32.  Now, how hard it is to make the code generator run in normal gcc, I don't know.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That exists: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=mingw&op=

Comment: Nitpicking, you could use a single version of a cross-compiler with different targets for different platforms.
"On the other hand, Clang/LLVM is natively a cross-compiler, meaning that one set of programs can compile to all targets by setting the -target option." - http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is making it easy, by allowing you compile code directly from Visual Studio on a Linux box. It's pretty cool.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/